# 502 error as I try to send back the headers to browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, http-headers

I am trying to send the following headers object back with my response:

```
    {
    "content-type": "text/css; charset=utf-8",
    "date": "Fri, 03 Jan 2020 06:44:37 GMT",
    "transfer-encoding": "chunked",
    "connection": "close",
    "set-cookie": [
        "__cfduid=d719a13f1aff03d4263084cf891fbe0691578033877; expires=Sun, 02-Feb-20 06:44:37 GMT; path=/; domain=.notion.so; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax"
    ],
    "x-dns-prefetch-control": "off",
    "x-frame-options": "SAMEORIGIN",
    "strict-transport-security": "max-age=5184000; includeSubDomains",
    "x-download-options": "noopen",
    "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
    "x-xss-protection": "1; mode=block",
    "referrer-policy": "same-origin",
    "content-security-policy-report-only": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://gist.github.com https://apis.google.com https://api.amplitude.com https://widget.intercom.io https://js.intercomcdn.com https://logs-01.loggly.com https://cdn.segment.com https://checkout.stripe.com https://embed.typeform.com https://platform.twitter.com https://cdn.syndication.twimg.com; connect-src 'self' https://msgstore.www.notion.so wss://msgstore.www.notion.so https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com https://notion-production-snapshots.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com https://api.amplitude.com https://api.embed.ly https://js.intercomcdn.com https://api-iam.intercom.io wss://nexus-websocket-a.intercom.io https://logs-01.loggly.com https://api.segment.io https://checkout.stripe.com https://api.unsplash.com; font-src 'self' data: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://js.intercomcdn.com; img-src 'self' data: blob: https: http: https://platform.twitter.com https://syndication.twitter.com https://pbs.twimg.com https://ton.twimg.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://github.githubassets.com https://platform.twitter.com https://ton.twimg.com; frame-src https: http:; media-src https: http:",
    "x-content-security-policy-report-only": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://gist.github.com https://apis.google.com https://api.amplitude.com https://widget.intercom.io https://js.intercomcdn.com https://logs-01.loggly.com https://cdn.segment.com https://checkout.stripe.com https://embed.typeform.com https://platform.twitter.com https://cdn.syndication.twimg.com; connect-src 'self' https://msgstore.www.notion.so wss://msgstore.www.notion.so https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com https://notion-production-snapshots.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com https://api.amplitude.com https://api.embed.ly https://js.intercomcdn.com https://api-iam.intercom.io wss://nexus-websocket-a.intercom.io https://logs-01.loggly.com https://api.segment.io https://checkout.stripe.com https://api.unsplash.com; font-src 'self' data: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://js.intercomcdn.com; img-src 'self' data: blob: https: http: https://platform.twitter.com https://syndication.twitter.com https://pbs.twimg.com https://ton.twimg.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://github.githubassets.com https://platform.twitter.com https://ton.twimg.com; frame-src https: http:; media-src https: http:",
    "x-webkit-csp-report-only": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://gist.github.com https://apis.google.com https://api.amplitude.com https://widget.intercom.io https://js.intercomcdn.com https://logs-01.loggly.com https://cdn.segment.com https://checkout.stripe.com https://embed.typeform.com https://platform.twitter.com https://cdn.syndication.twimg.com; connect-src 'self' https://msgstore.www.notion.so wss://msgstore.www.notion.so https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com https://notion-production-snapshots.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com https://api.amplitude.com https://api.embed.ly https://js.intercomcdn.com https://api-iam.intercom.io wss://nexus-websocket-a.intercom.io https://logs-01.loggly.com https://api.segment.io https://checkout.stripe.com https://api.unsplash.com; font-src 'self' data: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://js.intercomcdn.com; img-src 'self' data: blob: https: http: https://platform.twitter.com https://syndication.twitter.com https://pbs.twimg.com https://ton.twimg.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://github.githubassets.com https://platform.twitter.com https://ton.twimg.com; frame-src https: http:; media-src https: http:",
    "x-amz-id-2": "yU1usxBxEPUHVhSSBt7/FT0BQqrxGnijEJkyqfglWAvYsJkikQOJ4hs8KPwQ1EM/aQvoXWF1Ksk=",
    "x-amz-request-id": "E4268F0932B04530",
    "last-modified": "Mon, 02 Dec 2019 19:11:42 GMT",
    "etag": "W/\"975989b3d8843ca1c10efce3768964d3\"",
    "x-cache": "MISS from ip-172-31-144-69",
    "x-cache-lookup": "MISS from ip-172-31-144-69:3128",
    "via": "1.1 ip-172-31-144-69 (squid/4.4)",
    "vary": "Accept-Encoding",
    "cf-cache-status": "HIT",
    "age": "4845",
    "expect-ct": "max-age=604800, report-uri=\"https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct\"",
    "server": "cloudflare",
    "cf-ray": "54f301568e7de2fe-CCU"
}
```

but as I am trying, I get a 502 bad-gateway. I cannot understand the reason for this. What is it that I am doing incorrectly?

Here is how I am sending back the headers.

```
router.get("/", async (req, resp, next) => {
        const {headers, resource} = await downloadResource(someURL); 
        // Here headers is an object and resource is an ArrayBuffer
        resp
           .set(headers)
           .send(resource)

})
```

Is this not the correct way to send headers? If I remove `.set(headers)`, I get the data but I need to send the correct headers to the browser.

If it is helpful, I am trying to download the resource (a.k.a css) from https://www.notion.so/all-975989b3d8843ca1c10e.css via my proxy route (as shown above).

Comment: Are you sure that code is called? (test with console.log)

Maybe it runs another middleware.

Comment: Yes, it is being called. But somehow nginx sends back bad gateway @Hongarc